# Difference between git clone linux kernel on windows and ubuntu

Tags: git

I am having a Linux kernel git repository in gitolite. I am able to successfully 
     clone and compile the Linux kernel in my ubuntu PC. I cloned the Linux kernel on windows 
     using EGIT. Now i copied this source to ubuntu PC and compiled, it is giving me below compilation error.

```
 net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_ECN.c:20:42: fatal error: linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ECN.h: 
No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Now I tried `git diff > changes.patch`.
There are many changes which I have not done explicitly. I am not sure, whether windows is having any impact on these files.
These are some of the files, which are changed

```
net/netfilter/xt_hl.c
net/netfilter/xt_tcpmss.c
net/netfilter/xt_dscp.c
net/netfilter/xt_RATEEST.c
include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ECN.h etc
```

Comment: Som Git Versions (like git for windows) ask you on installation, if line breaks should be automatically converted from unix to linux (`core.autocrlf`), maybe that is causing your problem

Comment: What kind of changes are you seeing? Just line endings, or something more? Do the change go away when you run `git reset --hard`? Moreover, if the file `ipt_ECN.h` still in the repo, or is it actually missing?

Comment: What `git config --global core.autocrlf` return? Can you make sure it is set to false, then clone and try again.

Comment: Hi Vonc, git config --global core.autocrlf is not returning any value

Comment: Hi gturri, git status returning below data

Comment: deleted:    include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_TCPMSS.h
        deleted:    include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_connmark.h
        deleted:    include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_dscp.h
        deleted:    include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_mark.h
        deleted:    include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_rateest.h
        deleted:    include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ECN.h
        deleted:    include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ttl.h
        deleted:    include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_hl.h
        deleted:    net/netfilter/xt_RATEEST.c

Comment: Building the Linux kernel on Windows is not straight-forward: for one thing, Windows treats the `aux.c` file as a special device file, and that's not what the compiler expects!

Comment: Hi @ams i am not building linux kernel on windows. I was compiling it on ubuntu machine which got cloned from windows PC

Comment: This is cause windows filesystem is not case sensitive, then for windows have only one "xt_hl.c" and not the "xt_HL.c". I not find a solution for this, what I do is push only the real modifications when I need to do this in windows.